# tmux resize pane parameter understanding

Tags: tmux

In tmux, for resizing pane, I can use the command `:resize-pane -x 10`. I understand that `x` is for width and 10 is the cells. My question is from where are these 10 cells measured and is there a way to see total number of cells present on the screen?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cell should be one character. tmux provides some variables to get the cell size in pixels but this doesn't work for me, I guess this works only for a limited number of terminal emulators. Those variables are `window_cell_width` / `window_cell_height` / `client_cell_width` / `client_cell_height`.

If you need an accurate cell size in pixels, instead I recommend to query the size of the window in pixels using your OS tools and divide it by the window size reported by tmux. You can get tmux window size in cells via `window_width` and `window_height` variables:

`tmux display -p '#{window_width}x#{window_height}'`